# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

I want create dynamic WCF service channel in VS-2010 using ChannelFactory as follows.

I have one WCF service which is calling another WCF service using ChannelFactory as follows,

```
BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(_endpointConfigurationName);
using (ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory< IService >(myBinding))
{
factory.Open();
       object[] parameters = new object[1];
       parameters[0] = _documentId;
       IService proxy = factory.CreateChannel(myEndpoint);
       if (proxy == null)
        return;
       MethodInfo mi = proxy.GetType().GetMethod("DoExecute");
       if (mi == null)
        return;
       var serviceResult = mi.Invoke(proxy, parameters); 
       factory.Close();
}
```

“Web.config” file of called service as follows,

```
<services>
      <service name="IService.Service">
        <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="wsHttpBinding_IFTPUploaderService" contract="Service.IService ">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
       <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
       <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8752/Service/" />
            </baseAddresses>
       </host>
</service>
</services>
```

factory and proxy  is working fine but when “Invoke” method is executed it gives error as follows

There was no endpoint listening at `http://localhost:81/IService.Service.svc?wsdl` that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details

**Server stack trace**:

```
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

**Exception rethrown at [0]**:

```
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at SchedulerService.Service.IService.DoExecute(String id)
```

Comment: Why are you using reflection here to get the member? Based on the snippet this proves little to no sense to do.

Comment: Looks lke you should be calling `http://localhost:8752/Service/something`..  Can you pull the service up in a browser?

Comment: Based on the config file of the service you're calling, you should be using `WSHttpBinding` (not `BasicHttpBinding`), and as @zimdanen pointed out the address should be something like `http://localhost:8752/Service/ws`.